# How many connected components are there in the complement in $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the set $ \{(x,1/x)|x \in \mathbb{R} , x \neq 0 \}$

Tags: general-topology

How many connected  components  are  there  in the complement  in $\mathbb{R}^2$  of  the  set $ \{(x,1/x)|x \in \mathbb{R} , x \neq 0 \}$

**My attempt** : I think one

Take  $S= \{(x,1/x)|x \in \mathbb{R} , x \neq 0 \}$

$S^c= \{(x,1/x)|x \in \mathbb{R} , x \neq 0 \}^c=\mathbb{R}^2-S=\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}-S$

$\implies S^c=\{(x,1/x)|x \in \mathbb{R} , x =0 \}$

Comment: Look closely at what you wrote: $S^c=\{(x, 1/x)\ |\ x\in\mathbb{R}, x=0\}$. That not only isn't true but also doesn't make any sense, you can't divide by $0$. The complement is $S^c=\{(x,y)\ |\ y\neq 1/x\text{ or }x=0\}$.

Comment: okay  Got it .I thought  that  it can be  divide   by $0$ @freakish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. You will see that $\{(x,y): xy < 1\}$, $\{(x,y): y>\frac 1  x, x>0\}$ and $\{(x,y): y<\frac  1 x, x <0\}$ are disjoint connected sets whose union is the complement of $\{(x,\frac 1 x): x \neq 0\}$. So there are three components.

[Any two points of the first set can be joined by a line segment to the origin from the first, followed by a line segment from the origin to the second.

Any two points of the other two sets can be joined by a line segment.

Since path connected sets are connected it follows that the three sets are connected].

Answer (score 3):

There are 3 connected components. Consider the 3 sets
$$
A:=\{(x,y)\ |\ x<0,y<1/x\},\qquad
B:=\{(x,y)\ |\ x>0,y>1/x\}
$$
and
$$
    C:=\{(x,y)\ |\ x<0,y>1/x\}\cup\{(x,y)\ |\ x>0,y<1/x\}\cup\{(0,0)\}.
$$
Then these sets are disjpoint and their union is the complement of your set. Moreover, $A$ and $B$ are connected, because they are convex, and $C$ is connected, because it is star-like with center $(0,0)$.